# How can I add other currencies in Magento?

Tags: magento, admin, currency

Currently I'm building a webshop with Magento for a school project. I want to add other currencies on my webshop but when I go to System > Manage Currency > Rates and System > Configuration > Currency Setup, the only currency I see is Euro. I can't add other currencies to allowed currencies because the only currency I see is the euro. I see no other currencies. Am I doing something wrong, or do I have to add something on the ftp server? I hope that somebody could help me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdEH4.png)

Comment: check this article - http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-currency-selector-to-magentos-header/

Answer (score 1):

May I know which version of Magento you have installed ?

I am using Magento 2.1.8 and able to see different currencies.

If your intention is to just change the currency symbol, you can do that by editing stores ==> Currency Symbol. By doing this, entered currency symbol will be visible on your dashboard rather than euro symbol which is default currency in your case.